# Have user vote only once per topic but they can change their mind

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

I need help with logic. I have "useful" and "notUseful" button on reviews across my site. I made it so that when user clicks on them I get an object like `usefulness: { usefulResult: 1, notUseful: 0, useful: 1 },` so every time the user clicks a button the appropriate property gets incremented. and `usefulResult` is just `useful - notUseful`.

The main problem I'm having now is that I want one user to only be able to make one vote for a review but they could change their mind later. I know how to find out which user is doing the voting. but I can't think of the logic so the count wont increment more than 1 vote.

This is bad:
bad: user could keep clicking on notUseful button and the notUseful button counter keeps rising.

Info: The `usefulness` object has the count for all the users for a specific review so it could already be populated from previous data . so lets say the data was originally `usefulness: { usefulResult:-2 , notUseful: 5, useful: 3},` and a new user votes `useful` it should be  `usefulness: { usefulResult:-1 , notUseful: 5, useful: 4}`, if he then changes his mind and votes `notUseful` the object should change to `usefulness: { usefulResult:-3 , notUseful: 6, useful: 3}`.

Im working with mongoose and and express. I tried A bunch of stuff. Here's some stuff I'm working with. It might not make sense to you. Don't know what is wrong with me. Some stuff at the beginning is for other functionality. some of the stuff I previously tried is in comments.

```
    Reviews.findOne({companyName: comp , user : userId}).populate({
        path : "user",
        model : "Anon"
    })
    .then(function(returnedReview){
        console.log("returnedReview", returnedReview)
        // var returnedModel = new Reviews
        // returnedReview.usefulness = {}
        var mapped = returnedReview.userWhoVoted.toObject().map(function(e) {return e.userWhoVotedId.toString()})
        if(mapped.indexOf(app.locals.user._id.toString()) == -1){
            console.log("typeof app.locals.user.id---", typeof app.locals.user._id.toString())
            mapped.push(app.locals.user._id.toString())
        }
        var index = mapped.indexOf(app.locals.user._id.toString())
        console.log("--------INDEX----------", index)
        console.log("mapped User that voted?? --" , mapped)
        var checkForuserWhoVotedId= returnedReview.userWhoVoted.toObject().some(function(el){
            return el.userWhoVotedId.toString() == app.locals.user._id.toString()
        })
        var checkForWordUseful = returnedReview.userWhoVoted.toObject().some(function(el){
            return el.result == "useful" && el.userWhoVotedId.toString() == app.locals.user._id;
        })
        var checkForWordNotUsefull = returnedReview.userWhoVoted.toObject().some(function(el){
            return el.result == "notUseful" && el.userWhoVotedId.toString() == app.locals.user._id;
        })

        var userWhoVoted = returnedReview.userWhoVoted;
        var usefulnessObj = returnedReview.usefulness;

        if(userWhoVoted.toObject().length == 0){
            userWhoVoted.push({userWhoVotedId : app.locals.user._id.toString(), result : result})
        }else if(userWhoVoted.toObject().length > 0 && !checkForuserWhoVotedId) {

            userWhoVoted.push({userWhoVotedId : app.locals.user._id, result : result})
        }else if(userWhoVoted.toObject().length > 0 && checkForuserWhoVotedId && result == "notUseful" && checkForWordUseful){
            if(userWhoVoted[index].result){
               var indexed = userWhoVoted[index].result
            }


            userWhoVoted[index].result = "notUseful"
        }else if(userWhoVoted.toObject().length > 0 && checkForuserWhoVotedId && result == "useful" && checkForWordNotUsefull){
            if(userWhoVoted[index].result){
               var indexed = userWhoVoted[index].result
            }
            userWhoVoted[index].result = "useful"
        }

        if(!checkForuserWhoVotedId){
                if(result == "useful") usefulnessObj.useful++
               if(result == "notUseful") usefulnessObj.notUseful++
               userWhoVoted[index].nowUseful = usefulnessObj.useful;
              userWhoVoted[index].nowNotUseful = usefulnessObj.notUseful;
               console.log("usefulnessObj.useful : ",usefulnessObj.useful, "userWhoVoted[index].nowUseful + 1 : ", userWhoVoted[index].nowUseful + 1)
        }else if(checkForuserWhoVotedId){
            // console.log("usefulnessObj.useful : ",usefulnessObj.useful, "userWhoVoted[index].nowUseful + 1 : ", userWhoVoted[index].nowUseful + 1)
            if(result == "useful" && usefulnessObj.useful + 1 <= userWhoVoted[index].nowUseful ){
                usefulnessObj.useful++
                // usefulnessObj.notUseful--
            } 
            if(result == "notUseful" && usefulnessObj.notUseful + 1  <= userWhoVoted[index].nowNotUseful ){
                usefulnessObj.notUseful++
                // usefulnessObj.useful--
            }
            // if(result == "useful" && usefulnessObj.useful > userWhoVoted[index].nowUseful - 1){

            // }
        }

        // var upperBoundUseful = 
        // console.log("userWhoVoted[index].result ", indexed, " result: ", result)
        // if(indexed !== result){
        //     if(userWhoVoted[index].result =="useful"){
        //         returnedReview.usefulness.useful++
        //         returnedReview.usefulness.notUseful--
        //     }else if(userWhoVoted[index].result =="notUseful"){
        //         returnedReview.usefulness.notUseful++
        //         returnedReview.usefulness.useful--
        //     }

        // }   
        // if(indexed !== userWhoVoted[index].result)   




    //    if(result == "useful") returnedReview.usefulness.useful++
    //    if(result == "notUseful") returnedReview.usefulness.notUseful++
       returnedReview.usefulness.usefulResult = returnedReview.usefulness.useful - Math.abs(returnedReview.usefulness.notUseful);
    //    userWhoVoted = []
        returnedReview.save(function(err, doc){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(doc) console.log("doc", doc)
            res.send(doc.usefulness)
            // res.end()
        })

    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err)
    })
    // res.end()
}
```

object returned from save:

```
doc { _id: 57c760de1e08000300525775,
  updatedAt: Wed Sep 07 2016 03:32:29 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
  createdAt: Wed Aug 31 2016 18:57:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
  vote: 'up',
  reviewText: 'this sisisfrfr',
  company: 57c4f982a82a799432999b63,
  companyName: 'comp1',
  userType: 'anon',
  user:
   { _id: 57c760cf1e08000300525774,
     __v: 1,
     usefulness: [],
     reviews: [ 57c760de1e08000300525775 ] },
  __v: 2,
  className: '',
  createdString: 'We, August 31st 16, 6:57:34 pm',
  momented: '6 days ago',
  updatedString: 'We, September 7th 16, 3:32:23 am',
  userWhoVoted:
   [ { nowNotUseful: 0,
       nowUseful: 1,
       userWhoVotedId: 57cfc275e3ec2c3826ea55a0,
       result: 'notUseful' } ],
  usefulness: { usefulResult: 1, notUseful: 0, useful: 1 },
  statements:
   [ { name: 'statement2',
       question: 'This is the question for statement2',
       result: 6 },
     { name: 'statement3',
       question: 'This is the question for statement3',
       result: 9 } ] }
```

It got out of hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so your problem is you only want the user to have 1 vote, and you're looking for a good structure for this? Here is what I would do on a simplified comment structure:

https://jsfiddle.net/WilliamIPark/kuy0d1ec/5/

```js
var review = {
  author: '57c760cf1e08000300525774',
  content:'Some content', 
  usefulness: {
    useful: [
      '57c760cf1e08000300525774',
      '57cfc275e3ec2c3826ea55a0'
    ],
    useless: [
      '57cfc275e308000300a55a7',
      '57c4f982a82a799432999b63',
      '57c4f982f82a799400a55a7'
    ],
    total: function() {
            return this.useful.length - this.useless.length;
    }
  }
}
```

`review.usefulness.total()` will spit out the calculation, and it will be accurate so long as you keep only 1 instance of the user ids in the "useful" and "useless" arrays.

Obviously, you would then have a couple of functions to:

- Add a user ID into the `review.usefullness` object, to either `review.usefullness.useful` or `review.usefullness.useless`.
- Check for the user's ID existing already in either `review.usefullness.useful` or `review.usefullness.useless`, and add, do nothing, or remove from `review.usefullness.useful` or `review.usefullness.useless` depending on the check.

Comment: Interesting. with this way I don't have to do increment (++). just add and remove the ids to/from the arrays that get their lengths for the results. I'll work on this later. did I get the main point of your answer? thanks for showing me another way that might be helpful.

Comment: Correct. As long as you manage the ids to and from the 2 arrays correctly to avoid duplicates, this will work.

Comment: If you check out the jsfiddle code I've added a function to demonstrate voting up with the proper checks.